# 1/0 encountured solving Murphy ODE #116

Tags: differential-equations

This is another case of DSolve getting 1/0 internally.

Could someone explain why this happens? Is this a bug? does it happen on other platforms? I am using windows 7, 64 bit. This is a non-linear first order ODE which has known solution. ODE #116 from Murphy ODE collection.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the code and the result

```
ClearAll[y, x]
DSolve[y'[x] + Tan[x] Sec[x] (Cos[y[x]])^2 == 0, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This happens on 11 and 10.4 versions. Maple solves this and gives same answer as in the book:

```
restart;
ode:=diff(y(x),x) + tan(x)* sec(x)* (cos(y(x)))^2 = 0;
dsolve(ode,y(x));
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**update:**

fyi, send bug report to WRI. CASE:3807199

Comment: Same behavior in v9.0.1 and v8.0.4

Comment: `DSolve` should do something like `Integrate[Cos[y]^-2, y] + Integrate[Tan[x] Sec[x] , x] == c`, which yields the desired answer.  This certainly appears to be still another `DSolve` bug.

Comment: @bbgodfrey yes ofcourse, this is separable ODE and this is how I did it by hand. But computer algebra symbolic dsolvers use more "advanced" algorithms than we humans do on paper :)  I will send email to support@Wolfram.com now.